# Why are there suddenly sparkly particles in my well water?

Tags: well

I've contacted multiple well companies and no one can help me, so I'm asking here for alternate opinions. I moved into a new home and have been here for a year. I have a bored well about 75 ft deep and have had no problems with the water until now. My water looks milky/cloudy and is full of tiny sparkly particles that look like sand/sediment/salt. When it settles in the bottom of the glass, it looks light brown. There is no bad odor or taste. I will not accept an answer of "it's because it rained" because that's what the well companies keep telling me and it has NOT rained in weeks. I am having a dry summer. Last summer it poured every day and I did not have this problem. One well company half-heartedly suggested raising the pump, but did not offer to do so. I'm considering putting in a house filter, but I need to know if something is truly wrong with the well itself. It could be the casing, changes in the water table, etc.

I tried to think of anything that changed recently, and the only thing is that I had a large above ground pool removed near the well 2 months ago, uncovering an inch of sand. The well is 2 ft. higher than the sand and 15 ft. away. It seems unlikely to be making it all the way down into the earth. Is the sediment in the water caused by this sand? If not, what could be the most likely cause of the sediment in the water?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most local health departments will test drinking water to see if it is safe to drink.  A simple safety test is sometimes free, a test to find what is in the water might cost.  A bored well should be sealed so nothing on/above ground can get in.

Comment: 1. Did you recently use an unusually large amount of water? For example, in filling a new pool? 2. Please state what water treatment equipment such as filters, softeners, etc., are already installed on this system, if any. If the system is new to you and you don't know what the equipment is, edit your question and add photos of anything you can't identify by using the mountain icon.

Comment: If you suspect that a transient event (rain, moving pool, someone drilling a well "upstream" of your well) has caused an influx of sediment, you might try clear it by running lots of water from the well (e.g., run a garden hose full-on for a few hours or days). If the sediment remains, then that is your new normal; if it clears up then it was a transient event.

Comment: @MTA 1. It was near a day during which I had to do more laundry than usual and had also been watering new plants in the garden; however, I have since cut down on water usage but have seen no changes in sediment. 2. I don't have any water treatment equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Your say that the summer is dry in your area. This could mean the ground water table level is low, and that the pump starts to creates bubbles which makes the water look milky.

Regarding the brown sediment: You mention the recent removal of a pool. Was it made of concrete? If so, there could be calcium deposits that built up under the bottom of the pool, solved from the concrete. This material could fall off when the concrete was demolished and mixed up with the sand you mention.

Such deposits is initially white, but can turn yellow/brown over time (or even red if rust from the rebars is leaking through). The pool dried out the soil below it. When the spot is no longer protected by the pool construction, the calcium could probably travel quite far down in the ground, quite quickly and possibly even enter your well.

One simple experiment would be to try to add white vinegar (or other acetic acid) to see if the sediment starts to dissolve in the acidic water. If so, it is probably calcium.

If not, it is probably some sand.

I would be most worried about the level of the ground water table.

Comment: That is an interesting theory, but there was no concrete or demolishing. It was just a pool with a metal wall that was taken apart and rolled up.

Comment: Check if the water is coming through a softener. Those shiny particles could be the resin zeolite from the softner. If so the internal filter in the softener has failed.

Answer (score 1):

First, as far as a dry summer, it could be that your immediate area hasn't had a lot of rain, but the water table might be impacted by nearby areas. It really does depend on the aquifer, where water flows from/too etc.

When I hear "sparkly particles" this causes concern. I think metal, and frankly wonder if your pump is OK. Take a rare earth (read STRONG) magnet and pour it into a full glass of your water. See if any of these particles stick to it. If they do you confirmed they're ferrous metal, which could be your pump wearing out. Check your pump pressure... if it struggles (as compared to what it has been doing) to get to pressure, or maybe takes longer this might also be an indication the pump is failing.

Just an FYI: because you cannot smell anything doesn't mean there is not an odor. Had a city water issue before that my wife ad I could smell, kids couldn't. When we called the city they did have an issue related to some kind of algae that was harmless, and they said only 20% of people could smell it.

Comment: According to the previous owner, the pump is only three years old so I would hope it isn't failing already. How do I check the pump pressure?

Comment: I hear sparkly particles and think mica, first.

Comment: Pressure gage near your tank. Your system should be 40-50psi, but if you don't know what it was this may not be much help.

When I mention lower psi I'm referring more to what you might have noticed, or by hearing it mentioned realize there is a diff. that you hadn't thought about. So, think about whether it just takes longer to get to pressure than before.

The "sparklies" are coming from somewhere. While they could be natural it would at least be odd.

As far as age, they usually last a looong time. But new things do fail sometimes

Comment: @STS1SS Update: I finally got someone out to look at the well and they discovered that, not only was the cheap pump failing, its pumping cycle was 30-40 seconds long instead of about 10 seconds. So, it was just pumping and pumping, banging into the side of the well, and stirring up silt. However, the pump was not breaking apart. Anyway, I think your answer is probably closest.